# Blazor: Set focus on an element not work after submit

Tags: blazor, submit, setfocus, blazor-jsinterop, blazor-editform

this code when submit button entered invoked.
in "finally" i want to set focus to an InputText but it doesn't work.

```cs
private async Task SubmitBtn()
{
    if (_busy_submit_btn) return;
    _busy_submit_btn = true;
    try
    {
        var res = await myService.UpsertAsync(LetterId, myModel);
        if (res.Item1 != null)
        {
            myModel = res.Item1;
            await JsRuntime.ToastrSuccess(res.Item2);
            personsInMyModel = await myService.GetPersonWithLetterIdAsync(LetterId);
        }
        else
        {
            await JsRuntime.ToastrError(res.Item2);
        }

        myModel = new myDTO();
    }
    finally
    {
        _busy_submit_btn = false;
        await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("focusElementById", "NCode");
    }

}
```

Set focus on an element after submit

Comment: What is the `focusElementById` function?

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos it's a javascript function. i use it for another element in another place of my code and it worked correctly.

Comment: add a `@ref="myinput"` on the input and call `await myinput.FocusAsync()` when you need to focus it

Comment: @buga thanks! but this is not the solution. problem is anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using an EditForm - when I change model instance, it drops and recreates the elements in the DOM - so it will need to set focus in OnAfterRenderAsync instead.

Answer (score 1):

The page below demonstrates settting the focus on first load and after a submit.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<EditForm Model=this.country OnSubmit=this.Submit>
    <input class="form-control mb-3" @bind=this.country.Name @ref=this.firstElement />
    <input class="form-control mb-3" @bind=this.country.Continent @ref=this.focusElement />
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private ElementReference firstElement;
    private ElementReference focusElement;
    private Country country = new() { Name="Spain", Continent="Europe" };

    private async Task Submit()
    {
        //Do domething async
        await Task.Delay(100);
        await focusElement.FocusAsync();
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            // Set focus to the first input element in the modal
            await firstElement.FocusAsync();
        }
    }

    public class Country
    {
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string? Continent { get; set; }
    }
}
```